# Deploy grails application to jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, grails

I am trying to deploy Grails application using Jenkins. It throws the following exception.

```
Deploying /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/helloworld/build/libs/HelloWorld-0.1.war to container Tomcat 8.x Remote with context helloworld
      Redeploying 

[/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/helloworld/build/libs/HelloWorld-0.1.war]
      Undeploying 
[/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/helloworld/build/libs/HelloWorld-0.1.war]
      Deploying [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/helloworld/build/libs/HelloWorld-0.1.war]
    ERROR: Build step failed with exception



org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/helloworld/build/libs/HelloWorld-0.1.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:184)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1077)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1060)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1844)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/helloworld] but context failed to start
" instead of the expected "OK" message
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:715)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:761)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:101)
    ... 18 more
org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/helloworld] but context failed to start
" instead of the expected "OK" message
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:715)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:761)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:101)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:184)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1077)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1060)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1844)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Have you tried to deploy it on the localhost? Are tomcat versions the same?

Comment: What is grails version?